# How to override spread operation on a javascript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Class called `Myclass`

```
class Myclass {

 constructor(
    public title: string,
  ) { }

}
```

in the next example, I want to change the result of the **spread operation**

```
let myobject = new Myclass('hello');
console.log({...myobject});
```

result wanted for example

```
{
  new_title_name : 'hello'
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with overwrite?

Comment: JS does not support operator overloading. You can create a function that takes an object an returns another object.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done. The ECMA-262 specification describes [only one way a spread operator can work with objects](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-copydataproperties), with no ability to override it.

If you want to change the set of key-value pairs spread out, you need to provide a different object. Such an object can be generated by a function, method or a property:

```
class Myclass {
    get data() {
        const result = {};
        for (const k in this) {
            if (typeof this[k] === 'number')
                result[k.toUpperCase()] = this[k];
        }
        return result;
    }
};

const obj = new Myclass();
obj.a = [];
obj.b = null;
obj.c = 13;
obj.d = 'test';
console.info({ ...obj.data });
```

Comment: I will prefer to call it toPlainObj()